# simple UDP example/demo application for Delphi XE-7 and Indy 10.6.0.5169

Tags: delphi, udp, indy10, delphi-xe7

I'm looking for a simple UDP example/demo application for Delphi XE-7 and Indy 10.6.0.5169.

I've been looking for a while and everything I keep finding are for older versions of Indy or Delphi that no longer compile.

I need to implement the UDP Clients in order to handle WS-Discovery messages.

I tried to use the application listed here:

http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/code/src101105.zip

`SendBuffer` is giving me an error here:

```
procedure TUDPSearchForm.SearchPartner;
var
  x: Array[0..3] of Byte;
begin
  RadioGroup1.Items.Clear;
  RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := -1;
  Height := 50+13;
  Top := Top;
  Left := left;
  Show;
  IdUDPClient1.Host := '255.255.255.255';
  IdUDPClient1.Active := true;
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := True;
  x[0] := $00; // Search Receivers
  x[1] := $00; // Search
  x[2] := MessageCount div $100;
  x[3] := MessageCount mod $100;
  inc(MessageCount);
  IdUDPClient1.Port := UDPDefaultPort;
  IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(x, 4);
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := False;
end;
```

Comment: There are no examples specific to XE7.  If you have a particular demo you want to use, but it does not compile, then show the code and someone (probably me) will adjust it for you so it does compile.

Comment: I tried to use the application listed here:  http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/code/src101105.zip

Comment: I'm getting an error on:

Comment: SendBuffer is giving me an error here: TUDPSearchForm.SearchPartner;
var
  x: Array[0..3] of Byte;
begin
  RadioGroup1.Items.Clear;
  RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := -1;
  Height := 50+13;
  Top := Top;
  Left := left;
  Show;
  IdUDPClient1.Host := '255.255.255.255';
  IdUDPClient1.Active := true;
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := True;
  x[0] := $00; // Search Receivers
  x[1] := $00; // Search
  x[2] := MessageCount div $100;
  x[3] := MessageCount mod $100;
  inc(MessageCount);
  IdUDPClient1.Port := UDPDefaultPort;
  IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(x, 4);
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := False;
end;

Answer (score 2):

That example is meant for Indy 9.  For Indy 10, you have to use `TIdBytes` instead of a fixed array, eg:

```
procedure TUDPSearchForm.SearchPartner;
var
  x: TIdBytes;
begin
  RadioGroup1.Items.Clear;
  RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := -1;
  Height := 50+13;
  Top := Top;
  Left := left;
  Show;
  IdUDPClient1.Host := '255.255.255.255';
  IdUDPClient1.Active := true;
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := True;
  SetLength(x, 4);
  x[0] := $00; // Search Receivers
  x[1] := $00; // Search
  x[2] := MessageCount div $100;
  x[3] := MessageCount mod $100;
  inc(MessageCount);
  IdUDPClient1.Port := UDPDefaultPort;
  IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer(x);
  IdUDPClient1.BroadcastEnabled := False;
end;
```

You can simplify the code a little by using the `Broadcast()` method instead of `SendBuffer()`:

```
procedure TUDPSearchForm.SearchPartner;
var
  x: TIdBytes;
begin
  RadioGroup1.Items.Clear;
  RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := -1;
  Height := 50+13;
  Top := Top;
  Left := left;
  Show;
  SetLength(x, 4);
  x[0] := $00; // Search Receivers
  x[1] := $00; // Search
  x[2] := MessageCount div $100;
  x[3] := MessageCount mod $100;
  inc(MessageCount);
  IdUDPClient1.Broadcast(x, UDPDefaultPort);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm getting hung up on setting the "UDPSearchForm.OnUDPRead := UDPRead;" in the TForm1.Activate.  It needs a idUDPServer.TIdUDPListnerThread.

Comment: And what exactly about it are you getting "hung up" on? `TIdUDPListenerThread` is declared in the `IdUDPServer` unit, same as `TUDPReadEvent`. Make sure that unit is in your `uses` clause.